# Confusion on the integration of $\int_{-1}^{\sin(x)} 1 dt$.

Tags: integration

> In a few days I have an exam, and I want to know something about this.
>
> $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{\sin(x)} 1 dt$

My question is, what does dt mean in the integral?, and what is de procedure for doing this?

Comment: Did you mean $\int_{-1}^{\sin(x)}dt$ ?

Comment: yes thanks 1 dt

Comment: The answer is just $t$ evaluated in $\sin(x)$ $+1.$

Comment: Great! I didntknow if something changes if it is dt or dx

Comment: dt it's a 'dummy' variable, it could have been $d\lambda$ or $d\alpha$, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, $dt$ means that we are integrating with respect to $t$.

So in this case we have $$\int_{-1}^{\sin(x)}1dt=t|^{\sin(x)}_{-1}=\sin(x)+1.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int_a^b d t = b- a $$

In particular

$$ \int_{-1}^{\sin x} 1 dt = \sin x + 1 $$

Answer (score -2):

Dt is the element of length in R. It is used in differential geometry , for instance, to integrate in manifolds other than R itself (or an interval)